# dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged event with autopostback = false

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to handle dropdownlist `SelectedIndexChanged` event with `AutoPostBack property = false?`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using JavaScript. e.g.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function doPostBack() {
        setTimeout("__doPostBack('yourControlClientID','')", 0);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, just add the handler for selected index changed and it will be called back when the form is posted again.